# excel combining vlookup and some complicated calculations

Tags: excel, date, vlookup

Please consider the following

```
date    interest rate   2 dates    days between
1/5/11     10%           5/5/11
1/6/11     11%           8/7/11       64
1/7/11     18%
```

The dates shown are in format DD/MM/YY

I would like to calculate the median interest rate between the 2 dates shown.

```
So between 5th of may to 8th of july
26 days in may
30 days in june
8 days in july

in this example the median interest rate would be 
26/64*0,1
+
30/64*0,11
+
8/64*0,18

=0,1146875
```

is it possible to combine these calculation to a single cell in excel without the use of VBA?

Answer (score 1):

I think to put in a SINGLE CELL the calculation without VBA it's impossible... I think it's better (also to check) to divide in cells/columns. After Check, You can HIDE... Following the scheme:

[image]

In the following cells you put:

```
G2 -> =IF($D$3-A2+1>0;$D$3-A2-SUM(G3:$G$6)+1;0)
H2 -> =IF($D$2-A2+1>0;$D$2-A2-H3+1;0)
I2 -> =G2-H2
J2 -> =I2/$E$3*B2             ' A little correction...
```

and autocomplete...
In the cells J7 you put:

```
=SUM(J2:J5)
```

Comment: Thx for your input I wound up expanding my data to have 1 data point for every day instead of 1 each month. After that it was easy to solve with =sumifs(B:B;A:A;">=D2";A:A;"<D3")/E3